# Ошибка тестов: Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, юнит-тесты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс Person:

```
public class Person
    {
        public long Id { set; get; }

        public string Name
        {
            set
            {
                var regex = new Regex(@"^[А-ЯЁ][а-яё]");
                var match = regex.Match(value);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    Name = value;
                }   
            }
            get => Name;
        }

        public string DisplayName { set; get; }

        public List<Skill> Skills { set; get; }

        public Person(string name, string displayName)
        {
            Name = name;
            DisplayName = displayName;
        }

        private Person()
        {
        }
    }
```

UnitTest:

```
[TestFixture]
    public class PersonTests
    {
        [Test]
        [TestCase("Igor", "NickName", ExpectedResult = "Igor")]
        public string Test1(string name, string displayName)
        {
            Person person = new Person(name, displayName);
            return person.Name;
        }
    }
```

При выполнение теста вылетает такая ошибка

Comment: В чем вопрос то?

Comment: @tym32167 Как исправить ошибку

Comment: У вас ошибка "Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал соединение". Как предоставленный вами код относится к этой проблеме?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ при компиляции тестов это происходит, при компиляции проекта ничего нету. Написал тесты, скомпилил, ошибка

Comment: Представленный код к ошибке отношения не имеет, ищите ошибку в другом месте

Comment: @tym32167 а что может иметь отношение? я просто понятие не имею. Может я не так дебажу тесты или компилю не так?